# Where I can find high-res public domain images of Countries or Continents on the web

Tags: open-data, satellites

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Africa_(satellite_image).jpg) one of Africa:

[image]

That one is nice because it's > 3000x3000px which is large enough. I have looked around a bit for ones of these countries but haven't found anything that is large/high quality, free/public domain, and free of clouds/weather like the Africa image:

- United States
- Russia
- China
- India
- Mexico/Central America
- South America
- Canada
- Greenland/Iceland/Arctic
- Europe
- Australia
- Southeast Asia
- Japan

I would like to find these broad areas as images on a high quality satellite image similar to this Africa one.

Comment: You might search [opendata.se].

Comment: https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484 offers global images at 43200 x 21600 resolution (about 1km^2 per pixel), If you need higher resolution, try earthexplorer.usgs.gov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find satellite images free of clouds at [chinesse version of google maps](https://zhfw.tianditu.gov.cn/).

Under the rigth toolbar, top icon, you need to uncheck the first layer with the geographical names and click on the satellite image button, and you can place the view to see maps as this one of Southamerica.

[image]

Comment: Wondering if these are public domain licensed.

Comment: Not sure. I do not find anything else at wikipedia or other english sites than it is a **free** webservice, and I am not familiarized with rigth laws. I guess you can use the images quoting the source, but I cannot answer you that 100%

Comment: Translating http://bzdt.ch.mnr.gov.cn/ it can be read: "The standard map is compiled according to the national border painting standards of China and the world. It can be used for news propaganda drawings, book and newspaper illustrations, advertisement display background maps, handicraft design base maps, etc. It can also be used as a reference base map for the preparation of public version maps. The public can browse and download the standard map for free, and the drawing number is required when using the standard map directly."